# Change value of a model based on value of other model Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a models `Wallet` and `StudentPayment`. Every time I add or update StudentPayment, the `Wallet` balance should change based on the added or updated `StudentPayment`.

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    ...
    balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, default=0.00)
    ...


class StudentPayment(models.Model):
    ...
    wallet = models.ForeignKey(
                 Wallet, 
                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                 null=True, related_name='students_payment')

    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    ...
```

For Example:
if I add payment with 1000 amount, the wallet balance should change to 1000 too, I know how to do this, but don't know how to deal with the update, ex: if I change the payment amount to 900, the wallet balance should also change.
Appreciate any help)

I tried to implement with overriding save() method, but nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals should suit what you want here. Signals are fired after certain actions, like saving or deleting objects so you can execute a function when a `StudentPayment` is saved or deleted.

At that point you probably want the `Wallet` balance to be the total of all amounts for payments to that wallet.

```py
    from django.db.models import Sum
    from django.db.models.signals import (
        post_delete,
        post_save,
    )
    from django.dispatch import receiver


    class Wallet(models.Model):
        ...
        balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, default=0.00)
        ...
    

    class StudentPayment(models.Model):
        ...
        wallet = models.ForeignKey(
                     Wallet, 
                     on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                     null=True, related_name='students_payment')
    
        amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
        ...


    @receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=StudentPayment)
    def calculate_total_amount(instance, **kwargs):
     
        wallet = instance.wallet

        # Add together the amount of all `StudentPayment` objects for the wallet
        total = StudentPayment.objects.filter(wallet=wallet).aggregate(
            Sum('amount')
        )['amount__sum']

        wallet.balance = total
        wallet.save(update_fields=['balance'])
```

Some further reading for you on [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/) and [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/)